# Generate a dataframe of random numbers, but each column is restricted by lower an upper bound, and sum of row to be 100

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am looking to generate a DataFrame, filled with random float values, where the values in each column are bound by a list of tuples, defining lower and upper bounds. Additionally, each row in the dataframe should sum to 100. I tried adding a tolerance also to achieve 99.99. But my logic is somehow failing. The issue is that there are rows that don't sum greater or equal to 99.99.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

num_rows = 150
num_cols = 15

bounds = [(0, 20), (0, 10), (0, 15), (0, 5), (0, 10), (0, 5), (0, 20), (0, 10), (0, 10), (0, 5), (0, 5), (0, 10), (0, 5), (0, 10), (0, 10)]

tolerance = 0.1

df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((num_rows, num_cols)))

num_generated_rows = 0
while num_generated_rows < num_rows:
    for row in range(num_generated_rows, num_rows):
        row_sum = 0
        for col in range(num_cols):
            lower, upper = bounds[col]
            remaining_cols = num_cols - col - 1
            remaining_sum = 100 - row_sum
            if remaining_cols > 0:
                min_possible_value = max(0, remaining_sum - remaining_cols * upper)
                max_possible_value = min(upper, remaining_sum - remaining_cols * lower)
            else:
                min_possible_value = max(0, 100 - row_sum - upper)
                max_possible_value = min(upper, 100 - row_sum - lower)
            value = np.random.uniform(min_possible_value, max_possible_value)
            df.iloc[row, col] = value
            row_sum += value
        
        # Check if the row sum is within the defined tolerance
        if abs(row_sum - 100) <= tolerance:
            num_generated_rows += 1
            break
        
        # Stop generating rows if we've reached the desired number
        if num_generated_rows == num_rows:
            break

df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: *" But my logic is somehow failing."* Why do you say that?

Comment: Failing means, using this logic the dataframe has many rows which dont sum 99.99 @Corralien and AlexK

Comment: I found some values are greater than the upper bound? Try to use a same seed for np.random.uniform for reproducible example.

Comment: Why is it random? How "high-quality" does the randomness need to be-do you need a guarantee of uniformity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than to draw numbers between [lb, ub], you can draw numbers between [0, 1] that acts as coefficient. 0.25 for an interval of [0, 30] is 7.5 and rescale this coefficient to the right value after fixing new bounds (check comments).

You can use the following optimized code:

```
import numpy as np

bounds = [(0, 20), (0, 10), (0, 15), (0, 5), (0, 10), (0, 5), (0, 20), (0, 10), (0, 10), (0, 5), (0, 5), (0, 10), (0, 5), (0, 10), (0, 10)]
num_cols = len(bounds)
num_rows = 150

TARGET = 100

# 1st-pass, random generation
lb = np.array(bounds, dtype=float)[:, 0]
ub = np.array(bounds, dtype=float)[:, 1]

# Check feasibility
assert lb.sum() <= TARGET, f'Infeasible problem: sum(lb) > {TARGET}'
assert ub.sum() >= TARGET, f'Infeasible problem: sum(ub) < {TARGET}'

# x is a coefficient between 0 and 1
# y is a value between lb and ub
np.random.seed(42)  # for demo only
x = np.random.random(size=(num_rows, num_cols))
y = x*ub + (1-x)*lb

# Fix bounds
m = np.c_[np.sum(y, axis=1) < TARGET]  # below or above TARGET?
lb = np.where(m, y, lb)  # Change lower bounds to x if below TARGET
ub = np.where(~m, y, ub)  # Change upper bounds to x if above TARGET

# 2nd-pass, fix each values
LB, UB = lb.sum(axis=1), ub.sum(axis=1)
x = (TARGET-LB) / (UB-LB)
y = x[:, None]*ub + (1-x[:, None])*lb
```

**Note**: don't forget to remove `np.random.seed(42)`

Output:

```
>>> y
array([[12.12345246,  9.68966746, 12.4687076 , ...,  4.47247875,
         5.04041056,  4.84827506],
       [11.89476371,  6.54707803, 11.46217608, ...,  3.79461597,
         7.97722602,  5.26770304],
       [15.28289786,  5.01507058,  6.57181308, ...,  2.09846591,
         9.45503973,  5.54546481],
       ...,
       [18.39384868,  2.94238081, 12.9170368 , ...,  1.47846341,
         8.75263679,  1.3008411 ],
       [16.51397403,  7.29824288,  7.02829416, ...,  4.71439879,
         9.13096929,  8.04592187],
       [15.17896817,  9.36179865,  7.75855936, ...,  4.50037072,
         7.62359895,  4.75520839]])

>>> y.shape
(150, 15)

>>> y.sum(axis=1)
array([100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100.,
       100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100.,
       100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100.,
       100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100.,
       100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100.,
       100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100.,
       100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100.,
       100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100.,
       100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100.,
       100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100.,
       100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100.,
       100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100.,
       100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100.,
       100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100., 100.])
```

Comment: Thanks, @Corralien your solution is just amazing. Thanks for taking the time to write this answer. Additionally, you inspire me to write my Python programs like this. It's super fast even when I request Millions of rows, while perfectly doing what was required. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Corralien, your code works well with the kind of bounds defined in the problem. But if i have a bound list of mixed type.. it fails. For example if i want to use,  bounds = [
    (10.0, 19.0),
    (1.0, 21.0),
    (0.0, 10),
    (10.0, 0),
    (0.0, 16.0),
    (0.0, 0.5),
    (0.0, 0),
    (0.0, 0),
    (0.0, 0),
    (0.0, 0),
    (0.0, 0),
    (0.0, 0),
    (0.0, 0),
    (0.0, 0),
    (0.0, 0),
    (0.0, 0),
    (0.0, 0),
    (0.0, 0),
    (4, 4.2),
    (36.99, 37.0),
]

Comment: But in the data generated, bounds are [(10.49, 19.0),
 (9.15, 21.0),
 (0.07, 10.0),
 (0.0, 10.0),
 (3.68, 16.0),
 (0.0, 0.5),
 (0.0, 0.0),
 (0.0, 0.0),
 (0.0, 0.0),
 (0.0, 0.0),
 (0.0, 0.0),
 (0.0, 0.0),
 (0.0, 0.0),
 (0.0, 0.0),
 (0.0, 0.0),
 (0.0, 0.0),
 (0.0, 0.0),
 (0.0, 0.0),
 (4.0, 4.2),
 (36.99, 37.0)]

Comment: Thanks :-). It's easy to fix it. You just have to force the dtype as float. I updated my answer.

Comment: hi @Corralien. It still does not work with the range i specified above.

Comment: @kgmat. It works for me with or without forced dtype. What is your version of numpy? Here 1.21.5. I reused your bounds with mixed dtypes and it worked.

Comment: it is working as in it is giving output without any error, but please refer to my two comments above, if you use those mixed bounds. The bounds of generated number is not covering full range of bounds, please compare second tuple above, in the input bounds (1.0, 21.0) Vs the bounds of generated number (9.15, 21.0). Besides my NumPy version is 1.22.4

Comment: with NumPy version 1.21.5 also, the behavior is same.

Comment: `bounds` is a list of tuples or a numpy array?. What do you mean by *in the data generated*?

Comment: I provided bounds = [ (10.0, 19.0), (1.0, 21.0), (0.0, 10), (10.0, 0), (0.0, 16.0), (0.0, 0.5), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (4, 4.2), (36.99, 37.0)] in your code. Your code gives "y". i get 'min' and 'max' of all the sub-lists of "y" it comes out to be [(10.49, 19.0), (9.15, 21.0), (0.07, 10.0), (0.0, 10.0), (3.68, 16.0), (0.0, 0.5), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (4.0, 4.2), (36.99, 37.0)]

Comment: And how do you obtain y min and max? `y.max(axis=0)` and `y.min(axis=0)`? Do you have a random seed to be reproducible?

Comment: Random seed = 42, i mapped y on a Dataframe, df = pd.DataFrame(y), and used df.max() and df.min()

Comment: What's wrong with https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PZGx.png? Note for index 3, you have swapped lower (10) and upper (0) bounds but it doesn't matter for my code. Every min and max values are between lower and upper bounds, no?

Comment: There is nothing wrong at all, i agree. but in this image, row with index 4, i was expecting the difference between 0.0000 and 5.80176 to be minimum

Answer (score 1):

One (somewhat heavy-handed) approach is to use linear programming.

Advantages:

- your bounds are guaranteed to be respected
- your sum constraint is guaranteed to be respected and will be accurate
- it is vectorised, so you don't need `for`-loops
- the results are random-ish

Disadvantages:

- there are probably faster methods, though this runs "quickly enough".
- if you care about guarantees of random distribution uniformity: there are none here (though I'm pretty sure given your constraints that true uniformity is impossible)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.optimize
from numpy.random import default_rng
from scipy.optimize import Bounds, LinearConstraint

num_rows = 150
num_cols = 15

rand = default_rng(seed=0)

bounds = np.array((
    (0, 20), (0, 10), (0, 15), (0,  5), (0, 10), (0,  5), (0, 20), (0, 10),
    (0, 10), (0,  5), (0,  5), (0, 10), (0,  5), (0, 10), (0, 10),
))
cell_bounds = np.tile(bounds, (num_rows, 1))
perturbance = (cell_bounds[:, 1].min() - cell_bounds[:, 0].max()) / 2
lower = cell_bounds[:, 0] + rand.uniform(low=0, high=perturbance, size=num_cols*num_rows)
upper = cell_bounds[:, 1] - rand.uniform(low=0, high=perturbance, size=num_cols*num_rows)

A = np.repeat(a=np.eye(num_rows), repeats=num_cols, axis=1)

c_bound = np.full(shape=num_rows, fill_value=100)

result = scipy.optimize.milp(
    c=rand.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=num_cols*num_rows),
    bounds=Bounds(lb=lower, ub=upper),
    constraints=LinearConstraint(A=A, lb=c_bound, ub=c_bound),)
print(result.message)
df = pd.DataFrame(result.x.reshape((num_rows, num_cols)))
print(df)
```

```
Optimization terminated successfully. (HiGHS Status 7: Optimal)
            0         1          2   ...        12        13        14
0    19.695780  8.378342   0.102434  ...  4.444407  8.091462  9.073666
1    17.113129  9.108588  14.591218  ...  2.452088  8.309021  9.861998
2    18.569490  8.074654  13.583485  ...  3.475941  0.844778  7.541122
3    19.393683  8.766053   1.557968  ...  1.990811  8.882646  0.775763
4    19.836319  8.456286   0.226883  ...  4.442556  8.904374  2.308569
..         ...       ...        ...  ...       ...       ...       ...
145  19.226648  3.675740  13.277363  ...  1.632323  0.432656  1.095681
146  17.893662  8.960568  13.408240  ...  2.419953  1.104904  8.556052
147   1.376055  8.251378  12.722397  ...  3.709209  9.451243  8.980960
148  17.538430  8.255690  12.762953  ...  3.606618  1.019980  9.087719
149   0.817833  9.246465  13.594034  ...  4.184895  8.385792  1.716741

[150 rows x 15 columns]
```

Comment: Hi, this works well. But for a larger number of rows, for example num_rows =15000, This retursn MemoryError. Unable to allocate 25.1 GiB for an array with shape (15000, 225000) and data type float64

Comment: Because A is dense. Make it sparse and that problem will go away